# SQL for Contiguous Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns with start dates and end dates.

I would like to write a sql query in order to calculate the beginning of the period if it’s a continuation of the last month + one day  if I have a break of more than a day then I want to start from the beginning of that period

```
Ref     Start       End
----------------------------
6931    01/01/12    31/01/12
6931    01/02/12    29/02/12
6931    01/03/12    31/03/12
6931    01/04/12    30/04/12
6931    01/05/12    31/05/12
6931    01/06/12    30/06/12
6931    01/07/12    31/07/12
6931    01/08/12    31/08/12
6931    01/09/12    30/09/12
6931    01/10/12    31/10/12
6931    01/11/12    30/11/12
6931    01/12/12    31/12/12
6931    01/01/13    31/01/13
6931    01/02/13    28/02/13
6931    01/03/13    31/03/13
6931    01/04/13    18/04/13
6931    01/05/13    31/05/13
6931    01/06/13    30/06/13
6931    01/07/13    11/07/13
```

Ideally the above data set should look to have the values below when the query works

```
Ref     Start       End
----------------------------
6931    01/01/12    18/04/13
6931    01/05/13    11/07/13
```

Your help will be much appreciated, thank you in advance .. please ping me back if the above does not make any sense

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Are you wanting to group your data by quarter? MIN(StartDate), Max(EndDate) grouped by quarter?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to find a way to identify the dates that belong in the same period, then using Min/Max on each Group.

```
;WITH PeriodEnd AS
(   SELECT      [Ref],[End]
    FROM        #Periods
    WHERE       DAY(DATEADD(D,1,[END])) <> 1 --Get [End] dates that don't land on the last of the month
    UNION
    SELECT      [Ref],MAX([End])
    FROM        #Periods
    GROUP BY    [Ref] --Grab the last [End] for each [Ref], regardless of whether is lands on the last day of the month
),

PeriodGroups AS
(   SELECT      p.[Ref],p.[Start],p.[End],
                COUNT(pe.[End])OVER(ORDER BY p.[Ref],p.[End] DESC) AS Grouper --Assign a unique number to the dates in each period
    FROM        #Periods p
    LEFT JOIN   PeriodEnd pe ON pe.[End] = p.[End]
)

SELECT      [Ref],
            [Start] = MIN([Start]),
            [End] = MAX([End])
FROM        PeriodGroups
GROUP BY    Grouper,[Ref]
ORDER BY    1,2
```

EDIT: Enhancements based on Kevin Cook's feedback.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed4ae/7/0)

Comment: this code doesn't work with overlapping dates between groups.  Take 6931 6/01/2013-6/30/2013 and change it to 6941 4/01/2013-7/30/2013 and it shows 6931 being contiguous from 05/01 to 7/11 even when it's missing the whole month of june. fiddle for error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed4ae/1

Comment: Even with the partition it fails. Do this, create a new record for 6931 that is 01/02/2012 to 07/10/2013 and even though this covers the whole range of dates inside of the year, your code will still break it out into different chunks and not treat the range as one contiguous block. For data date with set start and end times that are next to each other this code works fine, but once you start getting dates that overlap, this doesn't work. fiddle for error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec58f/4

Comment: The solution may fail for your imagined data, but it works for the OP's stated scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Setup our test data (I added a new range of 6941 that covered 4-1 to 7-30

```
DECLARE @Periods TABLE
(
    Ref INT,
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Periods
VALUES
(6931    ,'01/01/2012'    ,'01/31/2012'),
(6931    ,'02/01/2012'    ,'02/29/2012'),
(6931    ,'03/01/2012'    ,'03/31/2012'),
(6931    ,'04/01/2012'    ,'04/30/2012'),
(6931    ,'05/01/2012'    ,'05/31/2012'),
(6931    ,'06/01/2012'    ,'06/30/2012'),
(6931    ,'07/01/2012'    ,'07/31/2012'),
(6931    ,'08/01/2012'    ,'08/31/2012'),
(6931    ,'09/01/2012'    ,'09/30/2012'),
(6931    ,'10/01/2012'    ,'10/31/2012'),
(6931    ,'11/01/2012'    ,'11/30/2012'),
(6931    ,'12/01/2012'    ,'12/31/2012'),
(6931    ,'01/01/2013'    ,'01/31/2013'),
(6931    ,'02/01/2013'    ,'02/28/2013'),
(6931    ,'03/01/2013'    ,'03/31/2013'),
(6931    ,'04/01/2013'    ,'04/18/2013'),
(6931    ,'05/01/2013'    ,'05/31/2013'),
(6941    ,'04/01/2013'    ,'07/30/2013'),
(6931    ,'07/01/2013'    ,'07/11/2013');
```

Here we get the dateranges of the data we are working with

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT @StartDate = MIN(StartDate) FROM @Periods
SELECT @EndDate = MAX(EndDate) FROM @Periods
```

This next part creates a numbers table to generate all of the dates of the range then we are going to take the id, the row number and the date offset group our data.

```
DECLARE @number_of_numbers INT = 100000;

;WITH
a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(@number_of_numbers)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
), 
dt AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT dt.CheckDate, p.Ref FROM
    (
        SELECT dt.CheckDate FROM
        (
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n.number, @StartDate - 1) CheckDate
            FROM numbers n
        ) dt
    ) dt
    INNER JOIN @Periods p
        ON dt.CheckDate >= p.StartDate 
        AND dt.CheckDate <= p.EndDate
),
t AS
(
  SELECT 
  dt.CheckDate d,
  dt.Ref,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ref ORDER BY CheckDate) i 
  FROM dt
)

SELECT 
    Ref,
    CAST(MIN(d) AS DATE) PeriodStart,
    CAST(MAX(d) AS DATE) PeriodEnd
FROM t
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY,i,d), t.Ref
```

Here is the output:

```
Ref   PeriodStart PeriodEnd
6931  2012-01-01  2013-04-18
6931  2013-05-01  2013-05-31
6931  2013-07-01  2013-07-11
6941  2013-04-01  2013-07-30
```